# How do I phrase what I'm looking for here?

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, google-search, terminology, google-chrome-devtools

There is a feature I'm looking for on Windows in the command prompt - and I don't think it exists - but rather than looking to see whether it exists in any way - I'm looking to see how to properly Google whether it exists.

I've confounded my brain trying to search for this, and I always end up with results that are so generic to the kind of thing I'm looking for as to be useless.

What I want is to have Autocompletion or Intellisense or (see this is my problem) whatever you call it in the command prompt.  But I want it to be the type of Autocomplete that is found in Chrome Developer Tools.  Where I start typing a word, and I can complete the word with Tab, but I have a suggestion of what my tab will complete...Check this screenshot:

[image]

Also, having something like this:

[image]

That would be pretty great.

As I said before, I don't think this feature exists in any command prompt software, but how would I describe what I was looking for, if what I was looking for was everything I said above.

The main thing I like about how Chrome Developer Tools implements it is that it is instantaneous, completely unobtrusive, and very easy and useful.  Many autocomplete implementations I have seen in the command prompt seem to be almost the exact opposite of what I just said I like about Chrome's implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Tab-completion is one more phrase you could try. I'm not sure how else to phrase it - intellisense, autocompletion are words I think of as standard for this.

A problem with putting this feature in the command prompt, compared to Chrome, is that JavaScript is a programming language and it's designed to be compiled and reflected on - Chrome can examine *window* and have a standard way to get all the properties, and then show them to you.

Windows/Linux command line programs are not designed to be interrogated - the OS sends the parameters in, and the program handles them however it likes. There's no standard way for the console to look at `example.exe` and tell you that it takes `/t username` as a parameter, or what it will do with it.

On Windows, PowerShell ISE (included with Windows, early versions were less good - latest version is downloadable with PowerShell 4 via [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx)) includes something close, rather because PowerShell is a mix of console and programming language. It is fairly fast, pops up automatically and filters as you type, shows you what tab-complete will do, and does not intrude over what you are typing. A lot like the Chrome example, although a more rectangular and less stylish.

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell ISE commandlet name tab-completion]

It also suggests completion for commandlet parameters:

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell ISE commandlet parameter tab-completion]

and object properties and methods:

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell ISE object properties tab-completion]

and file/path names:

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell ISE object properties tab-completion]

But it won't suggest command names unless they are PowerShell commands (*ja* won't suggest *java.exe*), and it can't handle parameters for normal Windows executables - as mentioned before, there's no way to do that in general. Linux might have an easier time if the Console could show you sections of a *man* page for the command, but that would still only be applicable to a few of all-possible programs.